# Утечка памяти в итераторе по датасету Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, итераторы

Необходимо реализовать итератор по изображениям в директории.

```
class DatasetReader(Reader):
    def __init__(self, log):
        super().__init__(log)

    @memory_profiler.profile
    def _get_arguments(self):
        self.dataset_name = self.args['DatasetName']
        self.dataset_path = self.args['DatasetPath']

        self.channel_swap = (np.asarray(ast.literal_eval(self.args['ChannelSwap']), dtype=np.float32)
                             if self.args['ChannelSwap'] is not None else [2, 1, 0])

        self.norm = (ast.literal_eval(self.args['Normalization'])
                     if self.args['Normalization'] is not None else False)

        self.layout = self.args['Layout']

        self.mean = (np.asarray(ast.literal_eval(self.args['Mean']), dtype=np.float32)
                     if self.args['Mean'] is not None else [0., 0., 0.])

        self.std = (np.asarray(ast.literal_eval(self.args['Std']), dtype=np.float32)
                    if self.args['Std'] is not None else [1., 1., 1.])

        self.image_size = ast.literal_eval(self.args['ImageSize'])
        self.dataset = list(Path(self.dataset_path).glob('*'))
        self.batch = int(self.args['BatchSize'])
        self.gg = Path(self.dataset_path).glob('*')
        self.max = len(self.dataset)
        self.transformer = Transformer(self.dict_for_transformer())

    def dict_for_transformer(self):
        dictionary = {
            'channel_swap': self.channel_swap,
            'mean': self.mean,
            'std': self.std,
            'norm': self.norm,
            'layout': self.layout,
        }
        return dictionary

    @memory_profiler.profile
    def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
        del image
        return image_resize

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    #@memory_profiler.profile
    def __next__(self):
        if self.n <= self.max:
            res = []
            for _ in range(self.batch):
                self.n += 1
                image = self._preprocess_image(str(next(self.gg).absolute()))
                res.append(image)
            res = np.array(res)
            result = self.transformer.transform_images(res, None, np.float32, 'data')
            del image
            del res
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Данный объект передается в функцию внешнего фреймворка. Однако после каждой итерации очень сильно растет потребление памяти (`del` вставлял в попытке решить эту проблему). Пример для 10 итераций.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    67    615.1 MiB    615.1 MiB           1       @memory_profiler.profile
    68                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    69    618.5 MiB      3.4 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    70    618.8 MiB      0.4 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    71    618.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del image
    72    618.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    67    882.0 MiB    882.0 MiB           1       @memory_profiler.profile
    68                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    69    883.1 MiB      1.1 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    70    883.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    71    883.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del image
    72    883.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    67   1001.2 MiB   1001.2 MiB           1       @memory_profiler.profile
    68                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    69   1002.1 MiB      0.9 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    70   1002.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    71   1002.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del image
    72   1002.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    67   1121.3 MiB   1121.3 MiB           1       @memory_profiler.profile
    68                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    69   1122.5 MiB      1.1 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    70   1122.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    71   1122.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del image
    72   1122.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    67   1241.6 MiB   1241.6 MiB           1       @memory_profiler.profile
    68                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    69   1243.7 MiB      2.1 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    70   1243.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    71   1243.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del image
    72   1243.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    67   1361.7 MiB   1361.7 MiB           1       @memory_profiler.profile
    68                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    69   1362.7 MiB      1.0 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    70   1362.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    71   1362.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del image
    72   1362.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    67   1482.0 MiB   1482.0 MiB           1       @memory_profiler.profile
    68                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    69   1482.3 MiB      0.4 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    70   1482.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    71   1482.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del image
    72   1482.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    67   1602.2 MiB   1602.2 MiB           1       @memory_profiler.profile
    68                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    69   1603.2 MiB      1.0 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    70   1603.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    71   1603.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del image
    72   1603.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    67   1722.3 MiB   1722.3 MiB           1       @memory_profiler.profile
    68                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    69   1723.5 MiB      1.1 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    70   1723.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    71   1723.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del image
    72   1723.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    67   1842.6 MiB   1842.6 MiB           1       @memory_profiler.profile
    68                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    69   1843.7 MiB      1.1 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    70   1843.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    71   1843.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del image
    72   1843.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    67   1962.8 MiB   1962.8 MiB           1       @memory_profiler.profile
    68                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    69   1964.3 MiB      1.5 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    70   1964.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    71   1964.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del image
    72   1964.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize
```

В чем может быть проблема данной реализации? Была необходимость проитерироваться по 32 изображениям, по итогу оперативка ушла в аут.
Код трансформера:

```
class Transformer:
    def __init__(self, converting):
        self._converting = converting

    def get_shape_in_chw_order(self, shape, input_name):
        layout = self._converting['layout']
        sort = np.argsort(LAYER_LAYOUT_TO_IMAGE[layout])
        shape = np.array(shape)[sort]
        chw = shape[1:]
        if len(shape) in [4, 5]:
            chw = shape[-1], shape[-3], shape[-2]
        return chw

    def __set_channel_swap(self, image, input_name):
        channel_swap = self._converting['channel_swap']
        if channel_swap is not None:
            image = image[:, :, :, channel_swap]

    def __set_norm(self, image, input_name):
        image /= [np.float32(255), np.float32(255), np.float32(255)]

    def __set_mean(self, image, input_name):
        mean = self._converting['mean']
        if mean is not None:
            image -= mean

    def __set_input_scale(self, image, input_name):
        input_scale = self._converting['std']
        if input_scale is not None:
            image /= input_scale

    def __set_layout_order(self, image, input_name):
        layout = self._converting['layout']
        if layout is not None:
            layout = LAYER_LAYOUT_TO_IMAGE[layout]
            image = image.transpose(layout)
        return image

    def _transform(self, image, input_name):
        transformed_image = np.copy(image).astype(np.float64)
        self.__set_channel_swap(transformed_image, input_name)
        if self._converting['norm']:
            self.__set_norm(transformed_image, input_name)
        self.__set_mean(transformed_image, input_name)
        self.__set_input_scale(transformed_image, input_name)
        transformed_image = self.__set_layout_order(transformed_image, input_name)
        return transformed_image

    def transform_images(self, images, shape, element_type, input_name):
        transformed_images = self._transform(images, input_name)
        return transformed_images.astype(element_type)
```

Код, в котором на основе итератора создается генератор и отправляется во внешний фреймворк (функция quantization_tvm, calibrate_dataset - генератор):

```
class QuantizationProcess:
    def __init__(self, log, model, dataset, quant_params):
        self.log = log
        self.quant_model = None
        self.model = model
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.quant_params = quant_params

    @memory_profiler.profile
    def calibrate_dataset(self):
        for i, data in enumerate(self.dataset):
            if i * self.dataset.batch >= self.quant_params.calib_samples:
                break
            yield {'data': data}

    @memory_profiler.profile
    def quantization_tvm(self):
        self.log.info(f'Starting quantization with calibration mode {self.quant_params.calib_mode}')
        if self.quant_params.calib_mode.lower() == 'kl_divergence':
            with tvm.relay.quantize.qconfig(calibrate_mode=self.quant_params.calib_mode.lower(),
                                            weight_scale=self.quant_params.weights_scale.lower(),
                                            dtype_input='int32', dtype_weight='int32', dtype_activation='int32',
                                            partition_conversions='enabled'):

                self.quant_model = tvm.relay.quantize.quantize(self.model.mod,
                                                               self.model.params,
                                                               dataset=self.calibrate_dataset())

        elif self.quant_params.calib_mode.lower() == 'global_scale':
            with tvm.relay.quantize.qconfig(calibrate_mode=self.quant_params.calib_mode.lower(),
                                            global_scale=self.quant_params.global_scale,
                                            dtype_input='int32', dtype_weight='int32', dtype_activation='int32'):

                self.quant_model = tvm.relay.quantize.quantize(self.model.mod,
                                                               self.model.params)

        else:
            raise ValueError('Wrong calibration mode parameter.'
                             'Supported modes: kl_divergence, global_scale')
```

https://github.com/apache/tvm/blob/main/python/tvm/relay/quantize/_calibrate.py в функции _kl_scale происходит итерация по датасету

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, который запускает итератор.

Comment: Да и `Transformer` что и как делает неизвестно, может он память ест. Кстати, у вас `self.dataset` вообще не используется в приведённом коде, зато в `self.gg` дублируются те же данные, только в виде итератора, а не списка.

Comment: Добавил код трансформера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После небольшого исследования (простой запуск итератора в цикле) выяснилось, что сам итератор тут не причем. Память течет внутри внешнего фреймворка. Если сравнить затраты памяти, которые выложены выше и которые внутри обычного цикла, то видно, что затраты памяти на итерацию не растут, но обрабатываются все изображения из директории.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    66    284.9 MiB    284.9 MiB           1       @profile
    67                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    68    286.2 MiB      1.2 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    69    286.5 MiB      0.4 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    70    286.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    76    284.9 MiB    284.9 MiB           1       @profile
    77                                             def __next__(self):
    78    284.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           if self.n <= self.max:
    79    284.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               res = []
    80    286.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           2               for _ in range(self.batch):
    81    284.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   self.n += 1
    82    286.5 MiB      1.6 MiB           1                   image = self._preprocess_image(str(next(self.gg).absolute()))
    83    286.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   res.append(image)
    84    286.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               res = np.array(res)
    85    286.7 MiB      0.1 MiB           1               result = self.transformer.transform_images(res, None, np.float32, 'data')
    86    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               return result
    87                                                 else:
    88                                                     raise StopIteration


(1, 224, 224, 3)
Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    66    286.7 MiB    286.7 MiB           1       @profile
    67                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    68    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    69    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    70    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    76    286.7 MiB    286.7 MiB           1       @profile
    77                                             def __next__(self):
    78    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           if self.n <= self.max:
    79    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               res = []
    80    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           2               for _ in range(self.batch):
    81    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   self.n += 1
    82    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   image = self._preprocess_image(str(next(self.gg).absolute()))
    83    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   res.append(image)
    84    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               res = np.array(res)
    85    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               result = self.transformer.transform_images(res, None, np.float32, 'data')
    86    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               return result
    87                                                 else:
    88                                                     raise StopIteration


(1, 224, 224, 3)
Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    66    286.7 MiB    286.7 MiB           1       @profile
    67                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    68    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    69    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    70    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    76    286.7 MiB    286.7 MiB           1       @profile
    77                                             def __next__(self):
    78    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           if self.n <= self.max:
    79    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               res = []
    80    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           2               for _ in range(self.batch):
    81    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   self.n += 1
    82    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   image = self._preprocess_image(str(next(self.gg).absolute()))
    83    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                   res.append(image)
    84    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               res = np.array(res)
    85    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               result = self.transformer.transform_images(res, None, np.float32, 'data')
    86    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               return result
    87                                                 else:
    88                                                     raise StopIteration


(1, 224, 224, 3)
Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    66    286.7 MiB    286.7 MiB           1       @profile
    67                                             def _preprocess_image(self, image_path):
    68    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    69    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           image_resize = cv2.resize(image, self.image_size)
    70    286.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           return image_resize


Filename: /home/vanya/projects/dl-benchmark/src/quantization/tvm/parameters.py
```

Comment: Так а какой конкретно фреймворк память ел, интересно? Может вы его как-то неправильно вызывали?

Comment: Apache TVM (https://github.com/apache/tvm). На квантизацию был только один пример и то, который удалили почему-то (https://web.archive.org/web/20230321100202/https://tvm.apache.org/docs/how_to/deploy_models/deploy_quantized.html). И по факту, по-другому квантизацию не вызвать, там одна такая функция.